# setting onLongClickListener prevents group item from expanding

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onlongclicklistener

I have an expandable list, but whenever I set an OnLongClickListener to a group item, it will no longer expand. If I comment the line:

```
setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { ... });
```

the list will expand on click.  With the long click listener attached, it stops expanding...

This is using the default methods implemented from BaseExpanableListAdapter..

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item, null);
    }

    // Set on long click listener to open navigation.
    // If I comment the code below, the group items expand on click.
    convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // Create new intent.
            Intent mapActivityIntent = new Intent(_context, MapActivity.class);

            _context.startActivity(mapActivityIntent);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try setting `setOnItemLongClickListener` for your `ExpandableListView` instead of each individual views?

Comment: I will try this and let you know tonight